# Volume of region between two intersecting spheres

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If i have two spheres, one of which is centred on the origin with a radius of $2$, and the other which is centred at $(0,0,2)$ with a radius of 2, how would i go about setting up the integral that represents the volume of the intersection of the two spheres, and then show that this volume is less than $6\pi$?
So far, I managed to figure out that $0<\theta<2\pi$ and $0<\phi<\pi$, and i think that $2<\rho<4cos(\phi)$, but i am not sure if this is correct and i have no idea how to show that the volume is less than $6\pi$. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It is probably easier not to work directly with spherical coordinates and instead exploit the symmetry of the system. Notice that the intersection is symmetric about $z=1$, so it suffices to integrate from $z=0$ to $z=1$ and then multiply by $2$. We can set up the remaining integral using disk integration. In fact, it will be geometrically clearer to integrate the top half of the lens, located between $z=1$ and $z=2$. Given $z\in [1,2]$, the radius of the disk at height $z$ is given by a simple application of the Pythagorean theorem as
$$r(z) = \sqrt{4 - z^2}.$$
Therefore our volume integral is
$$V = 2\pi \int_{1}^{2} r^2\ dz = 2\pi\int_1^2 (4-z^2)\ dz.$$
This integrate easily evaluates to
$$V = 2\pi\left[4z - \frac{z^3}{3}\right]_{z=1}^{z=2} = \frac{10\pi}{3}.$$
Incidentally, $6\pi$ is a very weak bound on the volume of the intersection. Notice that the total volume of each sphere is $32\pi/3$. The intersection of the two is clearly less than half the volume, so $V < 16\pi/3 \approx 5.33\pi$.